What is the alternate to xp_cmdshell in linux os
I am trying to run a stored procedure works fine in Windows, but the deployment server is linux with SQL Server service running in it. I am doing error logging using BCP. I found that xp_cmdshell is deprecated.
Is there any alternative way I can log errors to a text file in Linux?
Here's what I tried so far
CREATE PROCEDURE FactDataProcedure
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @ErrorCount INT = 0,
        @Body NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Cmd NVARCHAR(4000),
        @CurrentDate NVARCHAR(128);
         SET @CurrentDate = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120);

    SET @Body = 'An error has occurred in the SQL script. Please check the error log of File name : FactDataProcedureErrorLog_'+@CurrentDate+'.txt  for details.';

    --   Inserting 
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

          -- SQL Query here
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        EXEC LogSingleError;
        SET @ErrorCount = @ErrorCount + 1;
    END CATCH;

    IF @ErrorCount > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Cmd = 'bcp "SELECT ErrorMessage,ErrorProcedure,ErrorLine,ErrorTime FROM DB.dbo.ErrorLog WHERE ErrorProcedure = ''DataProcedure'' AND CONVERT(DATE, ErrorTime) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) " queryout "C:\SQLErrors\DataProcedureErrorLog_' + @CurrentDate + '.txt" -c -t, -S ServerName -T -a 65535';
        EXEC xp_cmdshell @Cmd;
    END
END;

--LogSingleError 

CREATE PROCEDURE LogSingleError
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ErrorSeverity INT,
        @ErrorState INT,
        @ErrorProcedure NVARCHAR(128),
        @ErrorLine INT;

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
        @ErrorProcedure = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-'),
        @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE();

    -- Insert the error details into the temporary error log table
    INSERT INTO ErrorLog (ErrorMessage, ErrorSeverity, ErrorState, ErrorProcedure, ErrorLine)
    VALUES (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState, @ErrorProcedure, @ErrorLine);
END;

I don't want to create a separate job for logging either

xp_cmdshell is off my default due to security risks for at least 15 years. Why is it used at all? Especially for data export, which is far easier and more efficient to do using SSIS? If you want to use bcp add it as the next step in your Agent job that processes your reporting data instead of calling it through SQL\

I don't want to create a separate job why? It's easier, safer, faster, more manageable.

You'd be much better off logging to a normal table then reading from that. Or log to the SQL Server Error Log and pick it up from there. SQL Agent has its own loggin system as well.
